# Error: Unable to access jarfile /rcon/rcon.jar

Tags: java

I'm working with a screen, and I entered a command into it, but it did not work.  I

Input: java-jar /rcon/rcon.

Output: jar: error: unable to access jarfile / rcon/rcon.jar.

When running from the root directory everything works. I would appreciate if you have the right command for the screen.

Comment: your command should be `java -jar <nameOfJarFile>.jar`. How are you compiling this code?

Comment: I need to run it from the root that is: java-jar /rcon/rcon.jar

Comment: can you post a picture?

Comment: check are you at the same place where jar is located. If not use the complete path of jar location. You are using wrong command java -jar /location of jar/xyz.jar

Comment: your command (unless you have an alias) is incorrect. It should be `java -jar`. Does the file `/rcon/rcon.jar` exist?